# Designing a spell to create works of art

Tags: spells, crafting, ars-magica-5

I want to create a spell that can create a big wooden statue.
The statue should not be basic and should be seen as a work of art.

As long as I want to create the exact same statue, this spell is simple to design:
*A CrHe spell Base 3 with a Size+1 modifier.*

But...
I wanna be able to create different statues with the same spell.
Such as a man wielding a sword, or an old guy reading a book.

**For now I have two leads:**

In the *Covenants* supplement, it may fit in the Craft-Magic category.
But Craft Magic is for Rego magic and not Creo.
There is a sentence saying:

> Creo  magic  draws  on  the  realm of  Forms  to  produce  things,  which  are always at least roughly right.

I don't know how to apply it to Creo magic.

In the *Corebook*, there is an example explaining how to use Requisites.

> Additional effects may not require a requisite if they are purely cosmetic. 
>   Thus, a spell that creates fire that looks like flaming skulls does not require  an  Imaginem  requisite.
>   A spell  that allowed the caster to choose how the fire looked would, because that flexibility is more than a cosmetic effect.

It would mean that I have to add an Imaginem requisite if I want to choose the shape.
But would it mean that I don't have to do a Finesse Roll anymore?

Comment: Related question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11532/i-want-to-build-a-castle-with-magic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is partially found in HoH:Societates in the Jerbiton chapter, page 60, "the creation of beautiful things."

Your guidelines above are wrong, as they do not account for the difficulty. First:

> When creating artificial objects,
>   the same level of Finesse is required as
>   when using Rego to make them from raw
>   materials.

Thus, you can use CrHe to just make a wooden horse, (as a ritual because it requires the expenditure of Vis. Therefore you'll end up making *lots* of wooden horses.). This ritual will also have a very high finesse requirement because "To do what a mundane artist could do in a year adds +9 to the Ease Factor."

Unfortunately, HoH:S offers little guidance on making *different* things with the same spell.

We can also find guidelines in the last chapter of Art and Academe, the sourcebook par excellance. On Page 132, we have: "The Covenants supplement contains rules for
creating mundane objects (page 49), specifically
craft goods, which can be used when a magus
creates a piece of artwork. In effect, the magus
copies the work of an artist in an instant, using
a Finesse roll to determine how successful he
is."

Happily, on page 133, we have an example of the spell that you're looking for:

> The Poet’s Bust
>
> ReTe Level 5
>
> R: Touch, D: Mom, T: Ind
>
> This spell changes a block of stone into a
>   carved bust. The caster must touch both the
>   targeted stone block and the person who is
>   the subject of the bust.
>
> (Base 3, +1 for stone, +1 Touch)

and, pertinent to an Herbam ritual:

> The Miniature of Immortality
>
> CrHe(An)(Te) Level 20
>
> R: Voice, D: Mom, T: Ind, Ritual
>
> This spell creates a painted miniature of
>   a person or scene within voice range of the
>   caster. The picture is painted on a wooden
>   panel, and the spell’s requisites include the
>   required mineral-based pigments and the
>   egg yolk necessary for binding the paint.
>
> (Base 2, +2 Voice, + 2 requisites, +1
>   complexity: minimum level for ritual spell)

In short, there is no trivial way of making a "generic statue making spell." However, with a high enough finesse, you can make a generic "make a statue of that type" spell, as a function of ritual and complexity and finesse. The artisans of house Jerbiton, however, view rego as a far more effective art for this purpose, as it can mimic the *tools* of the artisan rather than replicating the full process of the artisan. Each spell, therefore, is far simpler, easier to cast (and master), and more versatile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The part on Societates really helped me to understand how Creo Magic can be used to do art.
I think that I will change my spell to produce a big replica of an existing miniature.
That way, I won't have to add a finesse roll and with let the art thing to someone else.